# I don't see the "node_modules/bin" folder after installing browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I'm trying to repeat this tutorial:
https://ampersandjs.com/learn/npm-browserify-and-modules/#npm-browserify-amp-modules
But after installing browserify I don't see folder: `node_modules/.bin`

Instead I see a folder `node_modules/browserify`. Inside there is a `bin` folder, and Iinside of it - `cmd.js` and `args.js`.

How should I change this line of code in my case: `./node_modules/.bin/browserify app.js -o app.bundle.js` to compile all js files into one file? 
Or maybe I need to install browserify some other way?

Comment: Just add the subdirectory? `./node_modules/browserify/.bin/browserify app.js -o app.bundle.js`

Comment: @TimVermaelen but there are no "browserify" file in the bin folder... and. btw, what does this dot before .bin folder name means?

Comment: watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hvtnhx_8Q7A) @ 7:40 -ish

Comment: @MaximVelichkin some programs prefix folder/file names with a . to denote it should be a "hidden" resource. I believe Windows will often hide folders prefixed with a . automatically.

Comment: @TimVermaelen Thank you! Oh, I forgot to say - I work on a Mac. Perhaps this is why this method is not working for me?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Put together, the flow of creating a very simple web application with these tools **might look** something like this:*

You simply need to point your cmd prompt to the browserify node_module, so drop the `.bin` if it's not there => `/node_modules/browserify yourjsfile.js myjsfile.bundle.js`

As far as I can understand this guide: the `app.js` file or `yourjsfile.js` needs to have all the library requirements included in order for it to work.

```
var squareNumbers = require('./square-numbers');
```

This means you need to write this file as an entry point for all your scripts you need to bundle.

**TIP:** try to find a youtube video or something to get a better understanding of this guide.

The dot in front of these directories tells you it's a system folder, in this case, not of your operating system, but from another "system/application", like node. It puts these kind of folders alphabetically on top to make a distinction.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! "all the library requirements " -  how do you think, is an "underscore npm module" necessary? I have not installed it because, as I understand, I don't need it...

Comment: I just tried the method you wrote, but I got the  error message. I'll try to figure this out, anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: The guide you use also talks about the difference between frontend - and backend js. These days this gap is often closed => usefull in backend and in the browser. To make a point: if you need underscore for your website, I would first `npm install bower` and then `bower install underscore`. But that's just me. `npm` is a task runner, `browserify` is the task. `bower` could be your npm task to install frontend js for example. But that's maybe one step too far.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips and the video tutorial! I've never tried `bower` before. My main goal is simple - to fill the web page with the text from `JSON file` using `Handlebars`. To do this, I'm trying to use a `commonJS` module approach, and then compile all `JS files` into one via `browerify`. In the process many questions raises  :)